# Escaping Null Values From Quartile in SQl Server

Tags: sql-server

I have create a table and inserted some records.

```
CREATE TABLE #t 
   (
   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   val INT NULL
   );

--   INSERT 10 values: 3 NULL, 7 integers
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT NULL;
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT NULL;
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT NULL;
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT 5;
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT 7;
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT 8;
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT 9;
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT 9;
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT 11;
   INSERT INTO #t SELECT 12;
```

Now when i am executing script to find quartile

```
SELECT *,
  NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY val) As Q
FROM #t;
```

i am getting values as

```
ID val Q
---------
1 NULL 1
2 NULL 1
3 NULL 1
4 5 2
5 7 2
6 8 2
7 9 3
8 9 3
9 11 4
10 12 4
```

I don't want "Null" records and don't want to use "Where" clause.
I want result like this

```
ID val Q
---------
4 5 1
5 7 1
6 8 2
7 9 2
8 9 3
9 11 3
10 12 4
```

Comment: Well, what *do* you want?  Filtering out the `NULL` values seems quite sensible.

Comment: try using case in your select statement.

Comment: Please see the updated result

Comment: @AjeetSingh If you don't want `NULL` in the results, why not just use `WHERE val IS NOT NULL` - I know you have said you don't want to use `Where`, but I don't know why?

Comment: Thanks @GarethD. I know this is possible with "Where", but I want to know is there any other way that can be used with Quartile.

Comment: This is an exact copy and paste of [this 4 year old question on SQL Server Central](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1508622/Odd-to-me-Behavior-with-NTILE-and-NULL-Values-in-Source-Data), did you read through the solutions on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It strikes me that you might want `NULL` for the `NTILE()` value and to ignore the values for the calculation.  You can get this by doing:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL
             THEN NTILE(4) OVER (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN 'NOTNULL' ELSE 'NULL' END)
                                 ORDER BY val
                                )
        END) as Q
FROM #t t;
```

Or, perhaps more simply:

```
SELECT id, val, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY val) As Q
FROM #t t
WHERE val IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id, val, NULL as q
FROM #t t
WHERE val IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN val IS NULL THEN NULL 
    ELSE NTILE(4) OVER (
        --Split NULL and NOT NULL into 2 different groups
        PARTITION BY CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
        ORDER BY val) 
    END AS Q
FROM #t
```

You'll get:

```
ID  val Q
1   NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL
4   5   1
5   7   1
6   8   2
7   9   2
8   9   3
9   11  3
10  12  4
```